# Apache Flink set lateDataOutputTag of OutputTag type for WindowOperator

Tags: apache-flink

Recently I worked on flink, my app is just to count the record number based on TumblingEventTimeWindows,but there exists some records that come late, so I just want to count the late record numbers.

I read the WindowOperator source code :

```
// side output input event if
// element not handled by any window
// late arriving tag has been set
// windowAssigner is event time and current timestamp + allowed lateness no less than
// element timestamp
if (isSkippedElement && isElementLate(element)) {
    if (lateDataOutputTag != null) {
        sideOutput(element);
    } else {
        this.numLateRecordsDropped.inc();
    }
}
```

So how to set value for lateDataOutputTag while initialization?

Answer (score 0):

after read the source code of flink.
I find it is set by WindowedStream.sideOutputLateData();

```
datastream.keyby(...).window(...).sideOutputLateData(...)
```

WindowOperator is intialized by the WindowOperatorBuilder of WindowedStream.